# How to duplicate or copy item only with the latest language versions?

Tags: commands

Our customer had a request for possibility to copy or duplicate an item without a previous language versions. Only the latest versions have to be created.

Check my solution on http://sitecore-masters.com/en/2016/11/28/duplicate-item-without-previous-versions. Do you know any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an another example. What I am not happy that reflection and message collection are being used. But it can be as workaround for quick solution.

Configuration:

```
  <sitecore>
  <commands>
      <command name="custom:CopyLatestVersionTo" type="Sitecore.CopyTo.CopyLatestVersionTo, Sitecore.CopyTo" />
  </commands>
  <processors>
      <uiCopyItems>
          <processor mode="on" type="Sitecore.CopyTo.Pipelines.CopyLatestTo, Sitecore.CopyTo" method="OnlyLatestVersion" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Pipelines.CopyItems,Sitecore.Kernel'][@method='Execute']" />
      </uiCopyItems>
  </processors>
```

Command:

```
[Serializable]
public class CopyLatestVersionTo : Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.CopyTo
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        var args = new CopyItemsArgs();
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Items));
        var methodInfos = new List<MethodInfo>(instance.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic));
        var method = methodInfos.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Start" && m.GetParameters().Length == 4);
        args.AddMessage("command:copylatest");
        method.Invoke(instance, new object[] {"uiCopyItems", args, context.Items[0].Database, context.Items});
    }
}
```

Processor:

```
 public class CopyLatestTo
  {
    protected virtual void OnlyLatestVersion(CopyItemsArgs args)
    {
      var pipelineMessages = args.GetMessages(PipelineMessageFilter.Informations);
      if (pipelineMessages != null && pipelineMessages.Any(m=>m.Text == "command:copylatest"))
      {
        var copies = args.Copies;
        foreach (var copy in copies)
        {
          var currentVersion = copy.Versions.GetLatestVersion();
          foreach (var itemVersion in copy.Versions.GetVersions(true))
          {
            if (!itemVersion.Version.Number.Equals(currentVersion.Version.Number))
            {
              itemVersion.Versions.RemoveVersion();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Menu Item:
"/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Context Menues/Default/Copying/Copy Latest To"

[image]

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Indeed the efficient solution for this kind of requirement. Simply worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use for your requirement this module:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Smart_Tools_Add_Version_and_Copy_Content.aspx?sc_lang=en

a. It adds a new version to the selected destination language version.
If you have 3 versions it's adding just the last one.

b. It copies the content from the source language (context item) to all selected destination language.

c. It has the option of including the child items as well.

http://www.nehemiahj.com/2013/10/smart-tools-1-add-version-and-copy.html

Comment: Hi Climber, your comment is good, but it does not solve my problem. This tool copies only versions inside item. It does not create new item.

Comment: I added you a solution for one of the cases, you can download the module and decompile the bin files and check how it was made. You can extend it for the second case

Comment: OK, thanx for it.